# findViewById on custom view throws null

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-custom-view, illegalstateexception

Before I explain my problem, I want to say that I have already seen all the related questions but none of them worked for me.

I am a beginner in Android. I am using a custom view class, let's say CustomView which looks like:

```
class CustomView(context: Context?,attributeSet: AttributeSet) : View(context) {

    class CustomView constructor(context: Context?, attributeSet: AttributeSet){

    }
    var number = 1
}
```

I am inflating this view inside a fragment resource, like:

```
<com.example.myapp.CustomView
     android:id="@+id/custom_view"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

But now whenever I am trying to get the custom view, it is null. All the sibling views work fine.

```
val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,false)
val customView: CustomView = root.findViewById(R.id.custom_view)
```

It is throwing an error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: findViewById(R.id.custom_view) must not be null
```

Comment: why are you inflating view, why not just use CustomeView directly in fragment.

Comment: since the fragment has other components too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass that `AttributeSet` parameter into the `View` superclass constructor:

> To allow Android Studio to interact with your view, at a minimum you must provide a constructor that takes a `Context` and an `AttributeSet` object as parameters. This constructor allows the layout editor to create and edit an instance of your view.

(https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view#subclassview)

So:

```
class CustomView(context: Context?,attributeSet: AttributeSet) : View(context, attributeSet) {
```

If you like, this is the standard boilerplate, overloaded custom view constructor (that the IDE will generate for you):

```
class CustomView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : View(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)
```

That has some edge case theming compromises but it's usually fine, and handles whichever constructor the system wants to use.

(Also you don't need that nested `CustomView` class in your code)

Comment: this worked for me. But one more thing how do I get and update the number property and display the updated value in the fragment?

Comment: Are you sure you want to create a custom view? If so you should read some tutorials on it, it's a little advanced. If not my advice is don't bother, stick a ``TextView`` in your fragment's layout and update it in your fragment code. If you're a beginner, you really don't want to do this unless you have to!

Comment: Basically I wanted to implement it on a paint app where a CustomView serves as a canvas to draw and it will be inflated inside the fragment. So, I wanted to modify the pen size and color from the fragment. Before, I could do that I thought it would be better to understand how things work with a basic example, so I chose this. I am planning to have a public pen size property inside the custom view which I can update from the fragment and start to draw with new pen size.

Comment: Ok, you really need to read up on this, but you can either inflate a layout inside your custom view (like with a Fragment), or you can draw to a ``Canvas``, which is what you want to do. You basically implement ``onDraw`` and use the drawing commands (like ``drawText`` or ``drawLine``) using a ``Paint``. So if you want to write a number, you can use ``drawText``. But honestly, I feel like what you're doing is one of the more advanced uses of custom views (touch and everything) so finding a paint app tutorial might be your best bet, something that shows you how it all basically works